# Solving system of first-order PDEs with Frobenius theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

I've been stuck trying to solve this system:

$$\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{-2xy^2}{u} + 3y $$
$$\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{-2x^2y}{u} + 3x $$

Which must satisfy $ \ u(0,0) = 1$ and the solution lies on $u(x,y) = z$

I've started by choosing vector fields $ \ X = \ \left(1,0,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$  and $ \ Y = \ \left(0,1,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$ which by the Frobenius theorem must satisfy $\left[X,Y\right] =0$ where the brackets indicate the *jacobi brackets*.

Then to work out the flow of the X vector field:

$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1$ =>  $ x = t $

$ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 0$ =>  $ y = 0 $

$ \dfrac{dz}{dt} = \dfrac{-2xy^2}{z} + 3y$ where at $t=0, z= 1$

Now I am stuck integrating this last equation. I believe there is a simple trick such as making a substitution. Don't worry, this isn't homework

Comment: Could $z=\dfrac{1}{u}$ work?

Comment: No the solution is $z = u(x,y)$ .


The aim is to solve the flow for the X vector field with the intial conditions $x=0, y=0, z=1$ and then and then solve again for flow of the Y vector field with initial condtions $x = x, y=0, z= ?$ where the question mark indicates the solution to the vector field above

Comment: Sorry I mean the question mark indicates the solution to the integral I am stuck on. After this I will have a complete solution for z which as stated is u(x,y)